# Change Image on Click in React Native

Tags: reactjs, image, click, native

I am trying to create an app that changes to one of many images when the image is clicked. I have used touchable opacity and can make the image show an alert when clicked. I just can't get it to change to one of the many others in the file.

Here is all my code so far:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Component, Stylesheet, useState, TouchableOpacity, Button, View, Text, Image, ScrollView, TextInput, Alert } from 'react-native';

// main part of the app
const App = () => {
  

  var array = [require("./cards/card.png"), require("./cards/card2.png")]
  var x = 0
  

  //onclick function
  const handlePress = () => {
    //some logic
    alert("help")
    x+=1
  }
  
  // what shows up on the app
  return (

    <ScrollView>

      <View>
          <Text>{array[x]}</Text>
          <Text>{x}</Text>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={(handlePress)}
          >

            <Image
              style={{ 
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
              }}
              resizeMode="contain"
              source={
                array[x]
              }
            />

          </TouchableOpacity>

          </View>

      </View>

    </ScrollView>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

The other images that I want the card to change to are in the cards folder. What do I do to make it dynamic and change it to any of the other cards in the folder?

Comment: You x should be a react state

Answer (score 0):

in order to change image or any information in a screen that have been mounted, React have to re-render the screen and put the right information that you want.

To achieve this, you should use React states https://reactnative.dev/docs/state

Your code could be like this:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Component, Stylesheet, useState, TouchableOpacity, Button, View, Text, Image, ScrollView, TextInput, Alert } from 'react-native';

// main part of the app
const App = () => {
  
  const [card, setCard] = useState(0); //initial state

  var array = [
    "./cards/card.png", 
    "./cards/card2.png"
  ]
  

  //onclick function
  const handlePress = () => {
    //some logic
    //set card state to the next index
    setCard( current => current + 1);

    //so everytime you click function the state will change and this re-render your component with the new data.
  }
  
  // what shows up on the app
  return (

    <ScrollView>

      <View>
          <Text>{array[card]}</Text>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={(handlePress)}
          >

            <Image
              style={{ 
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
              }}
              resizeMode="contain"
              source={ require(array[card]) }
            />

          </TouchableOpacity>

          </View>

      </View>

    </ScrollView>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```